# Terraform output from a nested list

Tags: terraform

I am trying to get my output from my module in order to attach the iam policies I am creating to the roles I am creating. However it seems I am not getting the output to line up with my module. Code below will be what I have and then I'll show what I am trying to get with attaching it. when I try to add the attach it just starts complaining and I can't figure out why. Names for the roles will not always be the same length as in this case I just swapped out the names to test.

Example is attaching policy1 to role1 and then etc
Any help would be appreciated

within module folder
./modules/iam_dev/main.tf

```
locals {
    assume_policy = file("${path.module}/assume_policy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "dev" {
    for_each = var.roles
    
    name = each.key
    assume_role_policy = local.assume_policy
    managed_policy_arns = var.managed_policy
    tags = var.tags
}
```

./modules/iam_dev/vars.tf

```
variable "roles" {
    type = map(map(list(string)))
    description = "Roles to create"
}

variable "managed_policy" {
    type = list(string)
    description = "List of managed policies to be included with the IAM role"
    default = []
}

variable "tags" {
  description = "A map of tags to add to IAM role resources"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}
```

./modules/iam_dev/outputs.tf

```
output "role_name" {
  value = {
    for role in aws_iam_role.dev :
    role.name => {
      name = role.name
      arn  = role.arn
    }
  }
}
```

within my project folder this is what I have.
./projects/main.tf

```
module "iam_admin" {
  source = "../../modules/iam_dev"

  roles = {
    test1 = {
    }
    test2 = {
    }
    test3 = {
    }
  }
  tags = {
   Created     = "terraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "test_policy1"{
    name = "test_policy1"
    policy = file("${path.module}/json_files/test_policy1.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "test_policy2" {
    name = "test_policy2"
    policy = file("${path.module}/json_files/test_policy2.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "test_policy3" {
    name = "test_policy3"
    policy = file("${path.module}/json_files/test_policy3.json")
}

### tried the following few ideas but to no avail. I also assume the second one would apply to all which is not what I am wanting.
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test1" {
  role       = module.iam_admin.roles.test1.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.test_policy.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test1" {
  role       = module.iam_admin.roles.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.test_policy1.arn
}
```

edit:
Here is the error output. I tried it where I put the name in for example but same result.

module.iam_admin.roles.test1

```
71:   role       = module.iam_admin.roles
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.iam_admin is a object, known only after apply
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "roles".
```

Comment: " it just starts complaining" - is not specific. Exactly what is happening? What errors do you get? Which lines throw the error?

Comment: I added the error I am seeing up above and put the file structure above each block to make it easier to read. Line 71 throws the error when I try to do the attachment of the policy. Everything else works its just when I am trying to get the output of one of the role names in order to use it for the policy attachment is where the issue arises.